Cannot fully delete Boo app memory from iPhone
The Boo app is stuck in sign up mode and I want to log in to my account instead.
When I delete the app and reinstall, it opens in sign up mode. It clearly remembers that I was in sign up mode from before.
I looked through my settings and see no way to clear the app’s cache or anything.
Does iOS genuinely have no way to forcibly delete all data associated with the app off the phone? Something is clearly not being deleted.

It would be very unusual for iOS to delete the app but leave the user data intact. You could try shutting down the phone after deleting the app and restarting.
I don't know the app, but I would have thought that showing a sign-up page is what the app would do, fresh out of the box.
The problem seems to be how to sign in to an existing account from there.
I would ask the app's developers for help.

I've seen similar bugs in other apps that I've worked on where they store the device UID in a database, and use that to tell where you're at in the onboarding process, hence why it might persist even after deleting the app. Still a bad bug, though.
What you can try to do is just finish signing up with some throw-away email account, logout, and then back into the app using the email info that you want.
